# How to set up a trial-based account for users on an ubercart site?

Tags: 7, ubercart, users

I want to set up a trial based account for an user who will sell his products. After he paid the payment, i will upgrade him to `role seller`.

Until his role is upgraded to `role seller`, i don't want to show `add to cart` button for the added products.

First of all how can i differentiate it to be a trail site for example. 30days until he pays, if not i want the role to be expired. How can i do it. Any suggestions will be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create 2 user roles: Trial Seller and Seller.
2. Create a **Rule**.

   - Event: "Drupal is initializing"
   - Condition: User has role -> "Trial seller"
   - Action: php that will hide (disable) the add to cart button. You have to use the [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) function (or similar) like described here: https://drupal.org/node/773312#comment-7425408

The second question is another seperate task.

1. Create a **Rule**:

   - Event: "Drupal is initializing"
   - Conditions: User is of role "Trial Seller" AND not "Seller" AND php "(Current_date_time - Account_Created_Date) > 30*24*60*60" (to see if the time from the user account date until now is more than 30 days, time in seconds) AND he has paid
   - Action: Remove user role -> "Trial Seller"

There is also the module [Role_Expire](http://drupal.org/project/role_expire) that may help you.

Comment: First task i did using form alter and hide those add to cart buttons.

Second Task i used rules to do it.

Thanks